# Old password protected Zip files can only be opened with the original 1995 addZip v0.69 library?

Tags: encryption, compression, unzip, zip

My company has many many thousands of old compressed files that are maintained by a small program written many years ago.  The program successfully decrypts and decompresses individual files using internal addZip unzip calls (from Stephen Darlingotn's original addZip 0.69 library) but whenever I attempt to open the file manually with the password using 7Zip, WinRAR, or the modern PKZip, it tells me the password is not correct.

My initial theory was that the password I was given was incorrect, but I can clearly see it used in the DLL (The source is lost in time, but the decompilation lists and uses the password very clearly).

Is it possible that modern programs don't support older ZIP encrypted files?  The file PK header corresponds to a PK ZIP 2.0 file (created by addZip library v0.69), with encryption and normal deflation (per the PKZip spec), the first 10 bytes being...

```
50 4B 03 04  14 00 0B 00  08 00
```

The call made to encrypt/decrypt it seems very straight forward...

```
<Module>.addUNZIP_Decrypt(<Module>.std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.c_str(ptr3));

<Module>.addUNZIP_Overwrite(11);
<Module>.addUNZIP_InstallCallback(<Module>.__unep@?zip_callback@?A0xb8f18585@@$$FYGHFFPAD@Z);
<Module>.addUNZIP_View(0);
```

...with that ptr3 parameter on that first call being the pointer to the password.

Is it possible the way this is being called is somehow adding additional unprintable chars to the password?  I can't seem to find the source for the addZip library to validate it. ...and even if the password did have unprintable chars, I'm not sure how I'd feed that to a modern opening program.  The password isn't that long and has low entropy so I even tried brute forcing it with a few extra chars, but that didn't seem to do the trick (although I'm not sure it was even working because I'm starting to wonder if modern programs can read these zips).

I'm at a loss and the thought of manually and individually opening and saving 100000 documents is driving me to update my resume (kidding).

Comment: I was asked to post it here, as it was a more appropriate area.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware that I saw it on [crypto.se].

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation.

I ran some tests with a version of AddZip (v0.7 if I'm not mistaken) and I saw the same behaviour.

Investigating the issue I saw some references to the library stating that it is  shareware, not freeware as I thought, and that one of the limitations of the shareware version is that the password, no matter what you input, is "Unregistered".

In the version I was using it worked.

HTH,
Paulo